# Got 404 error during uploading file to YouTube

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, http-status-code-404, youtube-data-api

I have basic script for uploading video files and small pipeline to run its

The script is https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

It been worked fine couple of last months pretty fine, but I started getting 404 error from api server

There is the rich output

```
 /usr/bin/python2.7 push_video.py --file="/tmp/HofQ.mp4" --description="File name" --keywords="test" --category="22" --privacyStatus="private"
connect: (www.googleapis.com, 443)
send: 'GET /discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.googleapis.com\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nauthorization: Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMCzOovQCiAa0I-Mrz7oD-wWeikotEGLIRzk2Z6D2N7umFciU5RDQWZMKtBOXu-7gI_-v_ArhcNtTE9kNPnYHVYi32697vPBUC3be0sAi-kPHN9Utpi00gS1KDpa5gko8ZR_D_euZSzM_3VJrinOMe1jWIsS-WY\r\nuser-agent: Python-httplib2/0.17.2 (gzip)\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
header: Vary: Origin
header: Vary: X-Origin
header: Vary: Referer
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
header: Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2020 09:35:20 GMT
header: Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
header: Cache-Control: private
header: X-XSS-Protection: 0
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Uploading file...
connect: (youtube.googleapis.com, 443)
send: u'POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=status%2Csnippet HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: youtube.googleapis.com\r\ncontent-length: 142\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\naccept: application/json\r\nuser-agent: (gzip)\r\nx-upload-content-length: 155903894\r\nx-upload-content-type: video/mp4\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\nauthorization: Bearer xxxxxx_-v_xxxx\r\nx-goog-api-client: gdcl/1.8.0 gl-python/2.7.18rc1\r\n\r\n{"status": {"privacyStatus": "private"}, "snippet": {"tags": ["test"], "categoryId": "22", "description": "File name", "title": "Test Title"}}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
header: X-GUploader-UploadID: ABg5-UyUv6D3yHDBjVs6znCaTrtwA5GthyyHgrqOZNzB2uRy_QnO10h40rBmFEJMBQQvzwKggt7J-k4ulclMI2e9H90emRvk-A
header: Content-Length: 9
header: Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2020 09:35:20 GMT
header: Server: UploadServer
header: Alt-Svc: h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
An HTTP error 404 occurred:
Not Found
```

What I have tried to do:

- Run from another hosts, same problem
- Renew authorization, same problem

Many thanks for any help

Comment: I'm seeing this too...

Comment: Experiencing the same in the last few hours

Comment: Looks like 404 was gone, but after uploading I can't see files on WebUI: 

Video id 'rr6EH4PVpyE' was successfully uploaded

Comment: I see they have changes connect: (googleapis.com, 443) to connect: (www.googleapis.com, 443)

Answer (score 2):

Youtube fixed the issue by changing the rootUrl in https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest from https://youtube.googleapis.com/ to https://www.googleapis.com/